# Slicing a list conditionally

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
alist = [['color1'],
        ['clr1', '361', '0'],
        ['clr2', '1', '0'],
        ['clr3', '77', '0'],
        ['clr4', '660', '73'],
        ['color2'],
        ['clr1', '201', '0'],
        ['clr2', '25', '0'],
        ['clr3', '312', '73'],
        ['clr4', '132', '314']]
```

I need to split the list into smaller ones. The list contains lists. If there is an element(list) in the list of length 1 that is the starting point of splitting the list and stopping point is another element in the list of length 1. After splitting them move it to a list called nlist. So far I have coded the following :

```
idx = [i for i,x in enumerate(alist) if len(x) ==1]
idx.append(len(alist))
nlist = []
for i in range(0, len(idx)-1):
    nlist.append(alist[idx[i]:idx[i+1]])
```

And it does produce desired result as following:

```
nlist = [[['color1'],
        ['clr1', '361', '0'],
        ['clr2', '1', '0'],
        ['clr3', '77', '0'],
        ['clr4', '660', '73']],
        [['color2'],
        ['clr1', '201', '0'],
        ['clr2', '25', '0'],
        ['clr3', '312', '73'],
        ['clr4', '132', '314']]]
```

Is there a more pythonic approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the new lists in one loop:

```
split_list = []
for item in alist:
    if len(item) == 1:
        split_list.append([])
    split_list[-1].append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for creating the `nlist` as well:

```
nlist = [alist[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(idx)-1)]
```